# Transform для <a>

Tags: html, css, transform

Проблема в том, что применяю свойство описанное ниже, всё хорошо, но когда ссылка "a" лежит в теге "li" свойство не работает, чтобы сжать ссылку в "li" приходится использовать transform на самом "li", что мне совсем не нужно. Как быть?

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, span, a {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 0.9);
    transform: scale(1, 0.9);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: без примера сложно потестить, но самое правильное решение это использовать нужный шрифт, а не тянуть весь текст (который еще и сбивает отступы и верстку и жрет ресурсы). Но если хотите поправить, то думаю `display: inline-block` должен помочь

Comment: Дело в том, что в макете у всего текста есть свойство "Масштаб по вертикали: 90%", иного способа, кроме как использовать трансформ я не придумал. А от самого свойства отказаться не получится, так как текст не сильно заметно, но сплющен. Дополнил вопрос скрином из фш.

Comment: тег `a` это же inline ? а на inline трансформации не распространяются

Comment: Уже понял, сделал <a> инлайн-блоком. Спасибо